# ionic nested routes controller / templates never called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I try to realize a simple nested route in ionic.

```
.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
   $stateProvider
     .state('overview', {
        url: '/overview',
        templateUrl: 'event_overview/event_overview.html',
        controller: 'EventsCtrl'
     })
     .state('overview.event-create', {
        url: '/event-create',
        templateUrl: 'event_overview/event_create.html',
        controller: 'EventCreateCtrl'
     });
}])
```

The EventsCtrl is called und the template is shown up. But when  I navigate to the event-create route the address in the addressbar changes correctly but the controller EventCreateCtrl won't be called and the template also doesn't show up instead the old page is still shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could add your controller and template code as well. However, one problem might be that you don't have an `<ion-view></ion-view>` in your `event_overview/event_overview.html`.

Since your `overview.event-create` state is a child of your `overview` state, the ui-router will try to find a place to put your `event_overview/event_create.html` *within the event_overview.html* template.

Check out the [Nested States & Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) section of that linked page. Notice how the `contacts.html` includes a `<ui-view>` div for the child `contacts.list` state to live in.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think I used nested states wrong.. ich thought it would be correct to put the event-create "under" the event-overview... but I think to put in the same level is better

Comment: I hear ya... it took me a while to wrap my head around the `ui-router`, but it is super powerful once you understand the intricacies.